# ODBC x64 oracle problem

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, 64-bit, ms-access-2007

I have a workstation with Windows 2008 x64, MS Access 2007 and Oracle 11g x64
I use Access to connect to Oracle via ODBC.
I am the administrator (in the administrator group) on the workstation. I run Access as administrator but when I want to make an ODBC call to Oracle it does not work.

How do I do it:
I start MS Access and creates a direct query. In the properties dialog I go to add new and the Select datasource dialog appears. I then use machine datasource and click New, System datasource - but the driver for Oracle is not there.

Regards Robert :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Create a Virtual PC (Hyper-V) and install the 32 bit version of OS and client - it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Oracle supplied ODBC driver, you need to install the oracle client.  The default client install does not include the driver, so you either need to add it when you do the install or re-run the universal installer to add it later.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Oracle ODBC driver for 10g (don't know about 11):

- run the client install. You will be given 4 options for installation type: InstantClient, Administrator, Runtime, and Custom.
- select "InstantClient" (it's not in the Runtime install)
- You must install this in a new oracle home.

Once the installation is complete, you should see the Oracle driver in your ODBC control.

Answer (score 0):

I can se the Oracle driver in the standard ODBC administration but when I start this from within MSAccess the driver does noe appear. This means that the x64 driver is not present. if I look in the registry the Oracle driver is noe existing under the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI key like the ones for SQLServer